# Extjs timefield minvalue

Tags: extjs

I want to allow the user to select a start time and an end time.

When the 1st timefield has been selected I want the value of that field to become the min of the second field.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                items:[{
                    xtype:'timefield',
                    listeners:{
                        select:function(me, val){
                            me.up('window').down('[name=secondtimefield]').setMinValue(Ext.Date.format(me.getValue(),'h:i'));
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    xtype:'timefield',
                    name:'secondtimefield'
                }]
            }).show()
```

I got it all in a window so you can try it in sencha fiddle if you want to